# XSLT recursion - How can I improve?

Tags: xml, performance, xslt, recursion

I'm working on a conversion for big XML files (up to 15 Mb) and my conversion stops working on one recursion I have.

When I use a smaller test file it works fine, but with the big files the Saxon engine runs out of memory.

I have searched here and Google and tried some suggested solutions, but it still freezes up on me. So I was wondering if someone can take a look at it and point out some places to improve performance, or even a whole other way to do it.

What needs to be done: From the input I need to make a list of all the Articlenumbers and their corresponding new price-id's. These I need to be picked up in a following XSLT.

What I use:
XSLT 2.0 - Saxon 9.3.0.5 - 8,5 GB memory allocated

This is 1 Product from my input and there are about 14.000 in the final input:

```
<catalogus>
    <producten>
        <product>
            <type_id>simple</type_id>
            <zichtbaarheid>4</zichtbaarheid>
            <artikelnummer>12356</artikelnummer>
            <titel>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte</titel>
            <omschrijving>Donec metus sem, blandit a metus et, pulvinar tempus nisl. Vivamus
                sollicitudin, nulla ac sollicitudin scelerisque, felis libero eleifend ipsum, sed
                lacinia purus lacus sit amet arcu. Nulla aliquet ipsum maximus dui consequat
                vulputate. Nam vulputate viverra felis ac gravida. Maecenas semper lacinia finibus.
                Aenean non dui tristique, malesuada risus maximus, vulputate urna. Mauris sapien
                magna, euismod ut nisl vel, rutrum sagittis sem. Nam est metus, euismod ac aliquet
                nec, luctus sit amet neque. Nunc arcu libero, imperdiet ut risus sed, eleifend
                semper felis. Proin consectetur leo odio, sed faucibus eros posuere sed. Aenean
                lobortis risus risus, in dictum urna sagittis quis. Pellentesque nec purus semper,
                porttitor lorem sed, scelerisque elit. Sed eleifend lacinia tellus non tempor.
                Vivamus viverra in risus sed venenatis. Aenean semper dignissim nisi ut placerat. </omschrijving>
            <korte_omschrijving>Donec metus sem, blandit a metus et, pulvinar tempus nisl. Vivamus
                sollicitudin, nulla... &lt;a href="#description"&gt;Lees meer</korte_omschrijving>
            <merk>Lorem</merk>
            <merkid>189</merkid>
            <categorie>Main|Diversen|Surprisepakketten</categorie>
            <websites>TBD</websites>
            <voorraad>10</voorraad>
            <is_op_voorraad>1</is_op_voorraad>
            <btw procent="21">2</btw>
            <eigenschappen>
                <productafmetingen>
                    <gewicht type="g">365</gewicht>
                </productafmetingen>
                <kleur>Grijs</kleur>
                <geschiktvoor>Unisex</geschiktvoor>
                <verpakking>Retailverpakking (Karton)</verpakking>
                <materiaal>100% Polyester</materiaal>
            </eigenschappen>
            <systeemAttributen>
                <msrp_enabled>2</msrp_enabled>
                <use_config_min_qty>1</use_config_min_qty>
                <msrp_display_actual_price_type>4</msrp_display_actual_price_type>
                <hide_default_stockstatus>Yes</hide_default_stockstatus>
                <attribute_set_name>Default</attribute_set_name>
                <new_thumbnail_size>100</new_thumbnail_size>
                <opisop>0</opisop>
                <ebizmarts_mark_visited>0</ebizmarts_mark_visited>
            </systeemAttributen>
            <sinds>01-05-15</sinds>
            <gewijzigd>05-01-16</gewijzigd>
            <populariteit>4</populariteit>
            <barcode>646709510084</barcode>
            <image>830302.jpg</image>
            <small_image>830302.jpg</small_image>
            <thumbnail>830302.jpg</thumbnail>
            <media_gallery>830302.jpg;830302_2.jpg;</media_gallery>
            <media_gallery_position>1;2;</media_gallery_position>
            <media_gallery_exclude>0;0;</media_gallery_exclude>
            <nieuw>0</nieuw>
            <maxkorting>58.415599391959184</maxkorting>
            <korting>10</korting>
            <inkoopprijs type="exclBTW">21,4200</inkoopprijs>
            <inkoopactieprijs type="exclBTW">19,4727</inkoopactieprijs>
            <adviesprijs type="inclBTW">39,9500</adviesprijs>
            <verkoopprijs type="exclBTW">31,9835</verkoopprijs>
            <verkoopprijs type="inclBTW">38,7000</verkoopprijs>
            <actieprijs type="exclBTW">29,0759</actieprijs>
            <actieprijs type="inclBTW">35,1818</actieprijs>
            <margeEuro type="exclBTW">12,5107</margeEuro>
            <margeProcent>64.25%</margeProcent>
            <margeEuroActie type="exclBTW">9,6032</margeEuroActie>
            <margeProcentActie>49.32%</margeProcentActie>
            <status>1</status>
        </product>
    </producten>
</catalogus>
```

The data from ProductPrijzenAccess.xml:

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ProductenPrijzenAccess.xsd" generated="2016-01-22T16:16:14">
    <Producten>
        <Product-id>Kit-Busine</Product-id>
        <Product-naam>Business Kit</Product-naam>
        <datum-vanaf>2015-02-15T00:00:00</datum-vanaf>
        <datum-tot>2015-10-01T00:00:00</datum-tot>
        <opmerking>Voordeelpakket: B-Grip BH / B-Grip TA / Riemtas</opmerking>
        <Productgroep-id>11</Productgroep-id>
        <webshop>1</webshop>
        <actief>0</actief>
        <LeveranciersID>14</LeveranciersID>
        <Prijzen>
            <Prijzen-id>1052</Prijzen-id>
            <Product-id>Kit-Busine</Product-id>
            <datum-van>2015-02-15T00:00:00</datum-van>
            <datum-tot>2016-02-15T00:00:00</datum-tot>
            <verkoopprijs-ex-BTW>70.2397</verkoopprijs-ex-BTW>
            <inkoopprijs_x0020_ex_x0020_BTW>31.56</inkoopprijs_x0020_ex_x0020_BTW>
        </Prijzen>
        <Prijzen>
            <Prijzen-id>1086</Prijzen-id>
            <Product-id>144744</Product-id>
            <datum-van>2016-02-15T00:00:00</datum-van>
            <datum-tot>2017-10-01T00:00:00</datum-tot>
            <verkoopprijs-ex-BTW>202.4793</verkoopprijs-ex-BTW>
            <incl_x0020_BTW>245</incl_x0020_BTW>
            <inkoopprijs_x0020_ex_x0020_BTW>0</inkoopprijs_x0020_ex_x0020_BTW>
        </Prijzen>
    </Producten>
    <Producten>
        <Product-id>Kit-Care-S</Product-id>
        <Product-naam>Care for it Kit - S</Product-naam>
        <datum-vanaf>2014-12-11T00:00:00</datum-vanaf>
        <datum-tot>2015-10-01T00:00:00</datum-tot>
        <opmerking>Voordeelpakket - B-Grip BH / B-Grip RC / B-Grip HS / ANL S</opmerking>
        <Productgroep-id>11</Productgroep-id>
        <webshop>1</webshop>
        <actief>1</actief>
        <LeveranciersID>14</LeveranciersID>
        <Prijzen>
            <Prijzen-id>1045</Prijzen-id>
            <Product-id>Kit-Care-S</Product-id>
            <datum-van>2014-12-11T00:00:00</datum-van>
            <datum-tot>2014-12-31T00:00:00</datum-tot>
            <verkoopprijs-ex-BTW>82.64</verkoopprijs-ex-BTW>
            <inkoopprijs_x0020_ex_x0020_BTW>37.35</inkoopprijs_x0020_ex_x0020_BTW>
        </Prijzen>
    </Producten>
</dataroot>
```

The XSLT recursion I use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="NieuwePrijzenIDs">
                <!-- Get the current price-id's from external file from Access and sort them. -->
                <xsl:with-param name="AlleHuidigePrijsIDs">
                    <xsl:for-each
                        select="document('ProductenPrijzenAccess.xml')/dataroot/Producten/Prijzen">
                        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="child::Prijzen-id"/>
                        <xsl:element name="Prijzen-id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Prijzen-id"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:with-param>

                <!-- Parameter with total number of products that need a new Price-id. -->
                <xsl:with-param name="TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen"
                    select="count(producten/product)"/>

                <!-- Parameter with all products that need a new Price-id. -->
                <xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen">
                    <xsl:for-each select="producten/product">
                        <xsl:element name="Artikelnummer">
                            <xsl:value-of select="artikelnummer"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:with-param>

            </xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="NieuwePrijzenIDs">
            <xsl:param name="AlleHuidigePrijsIDs"/>
            <xsl:param name="TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen"/>
            <xsl:param name="ArtikelenToevoegen"/>


            <xsl:element name="Prijzen">
                <xsl:call-template name="NieuwePrijzenIDinhoud">
                    <xsl:with-param name="LaatsteGebruikteNummer"
                        select="$AlleHuidigePrijsIDs/Prijzen-id[position() = last()]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen"
                        select="$TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen" select="$ArtikelenToevoegen"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>


        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="NieuwePrijzenIDinhoud">
            <xsl:param name="LaatsteGebruikteNummer"/>
            <xsl:param name="TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen"/>
            <xsl:param name="ArtikelenToevoegen"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- If the total of products that needs to be added is bigger then 1, go on. -->
                <xsl:when test="$TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen &gt; 1">
                    <xsl:element name="PrijzenID">
                        <xsl:attribute name="Artikelnummer">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$ArtikelenToevoegen/Artikelnummer[1]"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>

                        <xsl:value-of select="$LaatsteGebruikteNummer + 1"/>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <xsl:call-template name="NieuwePrijzenIDinhoud">
                        <xsl:with-param name="TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen"
                            select="$TotaalAantalArtikelenToevoegen - 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="LaatsteGebruikteNummer"
                            select="$LaatsteGebruikteNummer + 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$ArtikelenToevoegen/Artikelnummer[position() != 1]"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="PrijzenID">
                        <xsl:attribute name="Artikelnummer">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$ArtikelenToevoegen/Artikelnummer[1]"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>

                        <xsl:value-of select="$LaatsteGebruikteNummer + 1"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:template>
```

The output should be:

```
<Prijzen>
      <PrijzenID Artikelnummer="12356">1177</PrijzenID>
</Prijzen>
```

Comment: You may also want to allocate more memory to the Java process.

Comment: Ghehe, I tried that. 8,5 GB isn't enough.

Comment: How about extracting `document('ProductenPrijzenAccess.xml')` into a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to show small but representative samples of all input documents and then explain the relationships and the results you want, I don't see why the verbal description "From the input I need to make a list of all the Articlenumbers and their corresponding new price-id's" requires recursion.

As for the posted code snippets, you seem to construct intermediary result elements in places like

```
            <xsl:with-param name="AlleHuidigePrijsIDs">
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="document('ProductenPrijzenAccess.xml')/dataroot/Producten/Prijzen">
                    <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="child::Prijzen-id"/>
                    <xsl:element name="Prijzen-id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Prijzen-id"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:with-param>
```

where I wonder if you can't simply sort the document once and use that sorted document so do e.g. with a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted-prices" as="element(Prijzen-id)">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="document('ProductenPrijzenAccess.xml')/dataroot/Producten/Prijzen/Prijzen-id">
    <xsl:sort select="xs:decimal(.)"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
```

where you would then have a sorted sequence of those `Prijzen-id` elements and could then use it with e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="AlleHuidigePrijsIDs" select="$sorted-prices"/>` or directly use the global variable.

Similarly in

```
            <xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen">
                <xsl:for-each select="producten/product">
                    <xsl:element name="Artikelnummer">
                        <xsl:value-of select="artikelnummer"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:with-param>
```

you construct new elements (admitted, with a slightly different name), it seems like selecting the existing ones simply with `<xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen" select="producten/product/artikelnummer"/>` would avoid constructing new elements. Of course the template would need to be adapted to then select `<xsl:value-of select="$ArtikelenToevoegen[1]/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="$ArtikelenToevoegen/Artikelnummer[1]"/>`.

Then later on you again construct copies of nodes in

```
         <xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$ArtikelenToevoegen/Artikelnummer[position() != 1]"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
```

where I wonder whether `<xsl:with-param name="ArtikelenToevoegen" select="$ArtikelenToevoegen[position() != 1]"/>` does not suffice to simply work with existing nodes.

As for an complete new approach, it might be that simply doing

```
<xsl:variable name="max-id" select="max(document('ProductenPrijzenAccess.xml')/dataroot/Producten/Prijzen/Prijzen-id/xs:decimal(.))"/>
```

in a global variable and then

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Prijzen>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="catalogus/producten/product/artikelnummer"/>
  </Prijzen>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artikelnummer">
  <PrijzenID Artikelnummer="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$max-id + position()"/>
  </PrijzenID>
</xsl:template>
```

suffices.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Now I see where the conversion has to do to much running around. My apologies for forgetting to include the second input file. I've added this input in the question now. Could you take a look with the added input if the recursion is actually needed? Would be a shame to test the changes you suggested to find out that the recursion isn't needed at all.

Comment: @TheRAH, I am not sure I understand the requirement, but it seems you just want to sort the `Prijzen-id` in the secondary document once to find the highest used there and then you want to assign `1 + highgest Prijzen-id` to the first `Artikelnummer` and then simply increase the number by one for any remaining `Artikelnummer`?

Comment: @TheRAH, I have added the answer and shown how you might be able to avoid the recursion, if I have understood what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ Martin Honnen, thank you again! That was indeed exactly what I was trying to do. You're new approach works like a charm and the whole document went trough like it should. I never thought about an other way besides recursive. Perhaps a bit of conversion blindness after all this time. Thank you for taking the time to explain the how and why! With your comment on the recursion I also improved some other ones I used. Got a 40% speed improvement on the whole conversion. Thanks!